# use ask method in pyromod

Tags: python-3.x, pyrogram

I want to use ask method in pyromod, but I have a problem
for use that, my code should be async? I don't want to change my code to async. so now how can i use ask method? how can i run it?

my code is:

```
from pyrogram import Client,
from pyromod import listen

client = Client(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

def get_code(chat_id):
    client.ask(chat_id, 'please Send me the code', timeout=30)

@client.on_message(filters.private)
async def start(app, message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        get_code(message.chat.id)


client.run()
```

**I don't want to write the getـcode function in an asyncio way.**

Answer (score 0):

It is async library, you have to remake your code. i dont know other ways.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyrogram import Client,
from pyromod import listen
import asyncio

client = Client(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

async def get_code(chat_id):
    response = await client.ask(chat_id, 'please Send me the code', timeout=30)

@client.on_message(filters.private)
async def start(app, message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        get_code(message.chat.id)


client.run()
```

You hadn't even imported asyncio.

> The ask method in pyromod is an asynchronous method

### Edit:

In sync way you can use threading.

```py
from pyrogram import Client
from pyromod import listen
import threading

client = Client(api_id, api_hash, phone_number)

def get_code(chat_id):
    def ask_code():
        response = client.ask(chat_id, 'please Send me the code', timeout=30)
        # Process the response here if needed

    threading.Thread(target=ask_code).start()

@client.on_message()
async def start(app, message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        get_code(message.chat.id)

client.run()
```